# Prove the contrapositive of "if $x + y + z$ is odd, then at least one of $x, y$, and $z$ is odd",

Tags: proof-explanation

I want to prove the contrapositive of this:  if $x + y + z$ is odd, then at least one of $x, y$, and $z$ is odd.

I think the contrapositive is this:  if at least one of $x, y$, and $z$ is even, then $x + y + z $ is even.

For the proof I'm not sure; I have something though. Assume $x$ is even, such that $x = 2k$ for some integer $k$, and assume $y$ and $z$ are odd, such that $y = 2c+1$ for some integer $c$, and $z = 2l+1$ for some integer $l$. $(2k)+(2c+1)+(2l+1).....$ not sure if I'm right or wrong to this point, but I don't know what to do. Can someone walk me thorough this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x+y+z$ is odd, then there exists one of them that is odd.

The contrapositive should be

If **all of** $x,y,z$ are even, then $x+y+z$ is even.

To see the proof, let $x=2a, y=2b, z=2c$, sum them up and factorize the $2$ out.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*  The negation of "*At least one of $x,y,z$ is odd*" is "*NONE of $x,y,z$ is odd.*"  In other words, "*All of $x,y,z$ are even.*"

Answer (score 0):

No - the contrapositve is

> If none of $x$, $y$ or $z$ are odd then $x + y + z$ is not odd

and the proof comes from finding a factor of $2$ on the right-hand side because of the factors of $2$ on the left-hand side

Answer (score 0):

In logic, you have a law called **DeMorgan's** which tells you that :

the negation of  (A OR B) is (NOT-A & NOT-B)

and , more generally, that

**the negation of  (A OR B OR C OR D OR ....)  is (NOT-A &NOT-B & NOT C & NOT D & ...)**

Knowing that the contrapositive of  IF X  THEN Y is :

IF **negation of Y**, THEN **negation of X**,

and knowing that, here, **the sentence that plays the role of Y** is :

**" (x is odd) OR (y is odd) OR (z is odd) "**

the contrapositiove of your original statement is :

if ( x is NOT odd) and (y is NOT odd) and (z is NOT odd)

then it is not the case that ( x + y+ z is odd) ,

or, if you prefer,

if **NEITHER x NOR y NOR z is odd,**

then it is not the case that ( x + y+ z is odd)